# Spring @Scope("token") in component @Component

Tags: java, spring, rest, scope, components

I have application with Angular 5 frontend and Spring 5 REST-backend. I need spring component, witch created one time for one token. If I been using non REST API I could use @Scope("session"). But now Session ID is different for each request.

I need that, because java.security.Principal in provides only username. But I need filtering my entities by customer ID.

I do not want to get customer from database while each request.

Comment: This sounds like a poor design--generally speaking, you want to design your system without long-lived state on the server to minimize scaling and upgrade problems. Java objects are generally cheap, and the usual approach is to create a new *whatever* for each request.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own scope . Read spring doc to [use a custom scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html) ,or  go to [Using custom scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-custom) . You will find plenty of examples,

Create a class TokenScope implementing Scope interface and use it as you use any other scope for a bean.

For a typical spring boot app

```
@Qualifier
@Scope("token")
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TokenScoped {
}
```

and use it.

```
@Component
@TokenScoped 
class SomeBean
```